# 'javax.persistence.RollbackException' recebido ao invocar escuta de ação '#{}

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Eu informo os valores na pagina, porem os valores nao são persistidos no banco.
é como se minha pagina nao enviasse os valores para as classes controladoras. Sim os valores sao informados no entanto, o erro é quando os valores são persistidos. Não sei como solucionar tal problema, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Page

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Novo Cliente</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event listener="#{cadastroClienteBean.inicializar}"
                type="preRenderView" />
        </f:metadata>

        <h:form>
            <h1>Novo Cliente</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                        actionListener="#{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisa"
                        outcome="/Pesquisas/PesquisaCliente.xhtml" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                style="width:30%; text-align: left;  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px"
                columnClasses="rotulo, campo, rotulo, campo">

                <p:outputLabel value="Nome Do Cliente" for="nomeCliente" />
                <p:inputText id="nomeCliente" size="40" maxlength="60"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.nome}" />

                <p:spacer />
                <!-- p:outputLabel value="Nome Vendedor" for="vendedor" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="vendedor">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a categoria" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroClienteBean.listaVendedores}"
                        var="vendedor" itemValue="#{vendedor}"
                        itemLabel="#{vendedor.nome}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu -->

                <p:outputLabel value="CPF" for="cpf" />
                <p:inputText id="cpf" size="40" maxlength="11"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.cpf}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Telefone" for="telefone" />
                <p:inputMask id="telefone"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.telefone}"
                    mask="(99)99999-9999" size="25" />


                <p:outputLabel value="E-MAIL" for="email" />
                <p:inputText id="email" size="40" maxlength="60"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.email}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Moto Desejada" for="moto" />
                <p:inputText id="moto" size="40"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.moto}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Agendar Contato" />
                <p:calendar id="dataTermino" size="25" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    navigator="true"
                    value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.dataHoraContato}" />

            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Service

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.honda.model.Cliente;
import com.nastek.repository.Clientes;

public class CadastroClienteService implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Clientes clientes;

    public Cliente salvar(Cliente cliente) {
        return clientes.guardar(cliente);
    }

}
```

Bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.honda.model.Cliente;
import com.honda.model.Vendedor;
import com.nastek.service.CadastroClienteService;

@ManagedBean
@Named
public class CadastroClienteBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Inject
    private CadastroClienteService cadastroProdutoService;

    private Cliente cliente;

    private List<Vendedor> listaVendedores;

    public void salvar() {
        System.out.println(this.cliente);
        this.cliente = cadastroProdutoService.salvar(this.cliente);
    }

    public CadastroClienteBean() {
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
        this.listaVendedores = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void inicializar() {
        System.out.println("iniciando...");

        //listaVendedores = manager.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vendedor v", Vendedor.class).getResultList();

        System.out.println(listaVendedores);
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public List<Vendedor> getListaVendedores() {
        return listaVendedores;
    }   
}
```

repository

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import com.honda.model.Cliente;

@Named
public class Clientes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Cliente guardar(Cliente cliente) {
        EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();
        cliente = manager.merge(cliente);
        trx.commit();

        return cliente;
    }

}
```

Error

```
fev 23, 2018 1:24:02 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
GRAVE: 'javax.persistence.RollbackException' recebido ao invocar escuta de ação '#{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}' para o componente 'botaoSalvar'
fev 23, 2018 1:24:02 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
GRAVE: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
    at com.nastek.repository.Clientes.guardar(Clientes.java:24)
    at com.nastek.service.CadastroClienteService.salvar(CadastroClienteService.java:18)
    at com.nastek.controller.CadastroClienteBean.salvar(CadastroClienteBean.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: valor nulo na coluna "cpf" viola a restrição não-nula
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 55 more

fev 23, 2018 1:24:02 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
GRAVE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException obtido durante o processamento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5: UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt25:botaoSalvar, Message=javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
fev 23, 2018 1:24:02 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
GRAVE: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
    at com.nastek.repository.Clientes.guardar(Clientes.java:24)
    at com.nastek.service.CadastroClienteService.salvar(CadastroClienteService.java:18)
    at com.nastek.controller.CadastroClienteBean.salvar(CadastroClienteBean.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: valor nulo na coluna "cpf" viola a restrição não-nula
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: Nosso idioma é o **Português**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Seu erro é esse: ERRO: valor nulo na coluna "cpf" viola a restrição não-nula. O CPF está vindo nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Como a [Giuliana Bezerra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54222/giuliana-bezerra) comentou, o erro é por causa do CPF que está nulo:

'ERRO: valor nulo na coluna "cpf" viola a restrição não-nula'

Esta é a exceção original do banco de dados, que provoca a exceção 'javax.persistence.RollbackException' do servidor de aplicação por estar em uma transação de banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Certo, no entanto, o valor CPf e todos os outros são informados na pagina!
Um exemplo disso é o debug colocado no método de salvar que tem na minha classe CadastroClienteBean. Como podem ver o valor nao vem nulo. ou seja, os valores informados na pagina são obtidos pela entidade, porem nao é persisdo no banco.

O erro de que o CPF está em branco irá acontecer para os demais campos caso eu remova o input CPF. Compreendem ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]